# Rails form_for multiple collection_select, values not selected on form failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure why, but my form is not showing the options selected on submit, even though the params hash shows that the information is being returned to the page.

Collection select code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :post_topic_ids, PostTopic.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Which renders:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="post[post_topic_ids][]" id="post_post_topic_ids">
  <option value="1">Psychology</option>
  <option value="2">Engineering</option>
  <option value="3">Nanotechnology</option>
</select>
```

Params returned after form validation error

```
params = {"post"=>{"post_topic_ids"=>["", "1"]}}
```

**Update**

I have also tried:

```
<%= select_tag 'post_topic_ids', options_for_select(PostTopic.all.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }), multiple: true %>
```

and:

```
<%= select_tag 'post_topic_ids', options_from_collection_for_select(PostTopic.all, "id", "name"), multiple: true %>
```

Which renders:

```
<select name="post_topic_ids[]" id="post_topic_ids" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">Psychology</option>
<option value="2">Engineering</option>
<option value="3">Nanotechnology</option></select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by my 'form is not showing the options selected on submit'?

Comment: Sorry what I mean is the options aren't selected when the form reloads ... After a form submit fails due to validation errors

Comment: Ok. I understood. Please post your controller code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify which element is selected a third parameter

```
<%= select_tag 'post_topic_ids', options_for_select(PostTopic.all.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }, --->selected_element<---), multiple: true %>
```

look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select for some examples.

Comment: I got it working with <%= f.collection_select :post_topic_ids, PostTopic.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @post.post_topic_ids}, { multiple: true, class: 'form-control' } %>